# When columns are seperated by multiple spaces, how to change a column and keep the spaces?

Tags: awk

I have a file where the columns are seperated by multiple spaces.

How can I set, let's say, the second column, and keep the spaces on the line?

For example, in postgres' pg_hba.conf there is a line

```
local  all   all          peer
```

How can I change 'peer' to 'trust' and keep the spaces as they are on the line? When I let awk do `$4="trust"` there will be one space between the columns. In principle that is OK, but it makes the file harder to read, because of the position of headers above the line in the file.

Comment: could you provide an example to clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: Use `-F'\t'` for the column separator and set the second column using `$2=...`.

Comment: I am sorry, I see that the columns are seperated by multiple spaces. But maybe that does not matter. The file is postgres' pg_hba.conf and one line  looks like:`local  all   all         peer`, How can I set 'peer' to 'trust' and keep the spaces as they are? The number of spaces between the columns is different, but stackoverflow does not show that.When I let awk to `$4=trust`, all the spaces between 2 columns collapse into 1 space.

Comment: Hey ericj, try to [edit] your question offering these details in the post. It improves the understanding of the question.

Comment: gawk-4.1.0:  awk -v FS="\t+" '{ print; printf("[1]=%s, [2]=%s, [3]=%s\n", $1, $2, $3); }'

Comment: This is a bit confusing: you mention that want to change the second column but then peer seems to be the 4th one (are all those multiple spaces meant to be tabs?). Note you can say `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$4="trust"}1' file`.

Comment: I am sorry. Yes, it is confusing. I thought the columns were seperated by tabs, but with `od` I saw it were spaces. And I should have said the fourth column. But if it were tabs, with `OFS="\t"` I get only one tab between the columns in the result. With `sed` it is very easy though, but then you have to know the content of the line, you cannot say: put 'trust' in the fourth column.

Answer (score 1):

here is one approach

```
$ echo "local  all   all          peer" | 
  awk 'gsub("peer","trust")'

local  all   all          trust
```

here is another approach if you're changing the field not by value but by index.  For example change third field to "trust" this time

```
$ echo "local  all   all          peer" | 
  awk -v RS='[^ ]+' -v ORS="" '{print $0 (NR==3?"trust":RT)}'

local  all   trust          peer
```

Comment: Don't do that, it will fail when `"peer"` appears as part of some earlier column. Try replacing field 3 (`all`) with `trust` with this approach.

Comment: You should mention the 2nd solution is gawk-specific. Plus it will only work if there's only 1 line of input, won't work if there's tabs between fields, and won't print a newline at the end of the output if you replace the 4th field.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a regexp and operate on the whole record by specifying how many initial fields (`\S+`) plus separators (`\s+`) to skip before making your change, e.g. with GNU awk for gensub() and `\s`/`\S`:

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/(\s*(\S+\s+){3})\S+/,"\\1trust",1)}1' file
local  all   all          trust
```

Changing field 3 is a harder/better test of any potential solution since it's contents (`all`) appear earlier in the line too:

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/(\s*(\S+\s+){2})\S+/,"\\1trust",1)}1' file
local  all   trust          peer
```

The regexp starts with `\s*` since by default awk ignores leading white space but that's not actually needed for your specific data.

With other awks you'd do:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){2}/) {
    head = substr($0,1,RLENGTH)
    tail = substr($0,RLENGTH+1)
    sub(/[^[:space:]]+/,"trust",tail)
    print head tail
}' file
local  all   trust          peer
```

Answer (score 0):

You really can't. If the amount of space varies between fields. Changing a field value will lead to rebuilding the record which means that the field separator `FS` is replaced by output field separator `OFS`.

You can try your luck with regex, though.